# Laravel 5.1 retrieve multiple input value and insert to db

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.1

I have an input form named `category` that can have multiple value just like `tags` input form in stackoverflow when you asking a question
I want to get all input value from that form and insert it into `category_service` pivot table
I use `$category = implode(",", Input::get('category'));` to get the array value
And then i get `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` error when try to insert it using this code:

```
foreach ($category as $category) {
    DB::insert('INSERT INTO category_service (category_id, service_id) VALUES (?,?)', array('$category', $service->id));
}
```

the tables look like this:

```
category_table
+----+--------------+
| id |   category   |
+----+--------------+
|  1 |  category_1  |
|  2 |  category_2  |
+----+--------------+

service_table
+----+--------------+
| id |   service    |
+----+--------------+
|  1 |   service_1  |
+----+--------------+

category_service_table //pivot table to store category id and service id
+----+--------------+-------------+
| id | category_id  |  service_id |
+----+--------------+-------------+
|  1 |      1       |      1      |
|  2 |      2       |      1      |
+----+--------------+-------------+
```

the `var_dump` result is `string(3) "2,1"`

Comment: Please provide some more details about your question. Also Add `Category` dump into your question,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$category = implode(",", Input::get('category'));`

implode make a **string** from the array

try

`$category = Input::get('category');
if (!empty($category) && is_array($category)) {
    foreach ($category as $val) {
        DB::insert('INSERT INTO category_service (category_id, service_id) VALUES (?,?)', array((int) $val, $service->id));
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

With PHP `implode` function you joining array to string and passing the string to foreach, as a result `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` error. You confused with `explode` ? See the official documentation. [Implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) and [Explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) . Also, it better to use plural and singular naming in foreach, like `foreach ($categories as $category)`.

And for Laravel insertion use:

```
DB::table('category_service')->insert(
  ['category_id' => $category, 'service_id' => $service->id]
);
```

Also, you put `$category` in a single quote and variable will not execute, it will pass as a string.

Also, you did you get `$service->id` ?

Comment: i got the `$service->id` value from another db query